# Fetch value from mysql table and display value as selected in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a very simple course catalog. I am using dynamic select drop down menus to display `courses` being offered by an specific `academy`. Initially, I am displaying the full list of `courses available` in theses select menus with values from mysql database table named `courses_selection_list`.   Then I am selecting courses being offered by `academy_id=15` by marking the values  `selected=selected`. In the Jquery/JS you will see that I am making a one time ajax call to file [`getCourses.php`](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/getCourses.php) where it then displays the select menus when the page loads.

My problem is the following: I am only able to display one value of the course being offered by `academy_id=15`. How can I display them all? Or is there a better approach to this? [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/course_offering.php)

[`courses_offering.php`](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/course_offering.php)

```
<script>
    var option = $('#courses_offered').val();
    showFields(option);

    function showFields(option){ 
        var content = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
            var content = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
                (function(i) {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                    url: "getCourses.php",
                        data: {
                            value: option
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            content += '<div id="course_'+i+'">'
                                +'<label>Course # '+i+'</label><br />'
                                +'<label>Course Name:</label>'
                                +'<select id="coursename_'+i+'" name="coursename_'+i+'" class="course_list">'
                                +'<option value="" >--- Select ---</option>"';
                            content += data;
                            content += '</select></div></br>';
                            $('#course_catalog').html(content);
                        }
                    });
                })(i);
            }
            $('#course_catalog').html(content);             
        }
        $('#course_catalog').html(content);
    }
</script>

<select name="courses_offered" id="courses_offered" disabled>
    <?php
    $db_select2  = $db_con->prepare("
        SELECT      academy_id
        FROM        courses_by_academy
        WHERE academy_id = :id
        ");
    if (!$db_select2) return false;
    if (!$db_select2->execute(array(':id' => $id))) return false;
    $courses_count = $db_select2->rowCount();
    echo "<option>----Select----</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"1\"". (($courses_count=="1")?"selected=\"selected\"":"") .">1</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"2\"". (($courses_count=="2")?"selected=\"selected\"":"") .">2</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"3\"". (($courses_count=="3")?"selected=\"selected\"":"") .">3</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"4\"". (($courses_count=="4")?"selected=\"selected\"":"") .">4</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"5\"". (($courses_count=="5")?"selected=\"selected\"":"") .">5</option>";
    ?>
</select>
<div id="course_catalog"></div>
```

[`getCourses.php`](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/getCourses.php) - courses values

```
$id = 15;
//get the course list
$course_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses_selection_list;");
$course_query->execute();

$data = $course_query->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row){
    //select the courses being offered by academy_id=15
    $option = "<option value='".$row["course_id"].":".$row["course_name"]."'";
    $db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
        SELECT academy_id, course_name, course_id, 
               course_start_date, course_end_date
        FROM courses_by_academy
        WHERE academy_id = :id
    ");
    if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':id' => $id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    foreach ($results as $value) {
        $result= $value['course_id'];
        if ($result == $row['course_id']) {
            $option .= "selected='selected'";
        }            
    }
    $option .= ">". $row['course_name'] ."</option>";
    //show result
    echo $option;            
}
```

*Mysql Tables Example:*

`courses_selection_list`

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| course_id |       course_name       |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|         1 | Math                    |
|         2 | English                 |
|         3 | Science                 |
|         4 | Other- Not Listed       |
|         5 | Social Studies          | 
|         6 | Home Mac                |  
|         7 | Business Management     | 
|         8 | Psychology              | 
|         9 | Accounting              | 
|        10 | Advanced Networks       |  
|        11 | Information Techonology |  
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

`courses_by_academy`

```
+----+------------+--------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id | academy_id |  course_name             | course_id | start_date |end_date  |
+----+------------+--------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|  1 |         15 | Science                  |         3 |2013-12-04  |2013-12-25|
|  2 |         15 | Business Management      |         7 |2013-12-04  |2013-12-25|
|  3 |         15 | Information Technology   |        11 |2013-12-04  |2013-12-25|
+----+------------+--------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: can you narrow down code shown to relevant code to issue only. Not clear whether your problem is php or script. Have no idea what demo should do

Comment: why are you making multiple ajax call, in for loop?

Comment: @RaunakKathuria How would you suggest to go about it?

Comment: @charlietfl The problem is in the script. Sorry about the overwhelming code. The [dropdown menu](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/course_offering.php) is suppose to show the selected values found [here](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/getCourses.php).

Comment: inspect the live html inside select using browser console/dev tools...will see a textnode with `"` in it. Is from `Select ---</option>"';` Try removing double quote after `</option>`

Comment: @charlietfl. Sorry it seems that I am not being clear. I have posted an image of the desired result. I would like to display the value from `courses_by_academy` as selected inside the dropdown menu

Comment: right...but the `selected` property set on `<option>` tags is not being recognized due to invalid html within the `select` tag itself

Comment: @charlietfl Alright, I followed your comment and removed the `"`. But now what do i need to do next to get the desired result?

Comment: ok...missing a space between `value` and  before `selected` in the php generated options. ALso...php outpuing 2 `selected` ....look in live html, or ajax response...will see `selected` on last option also

Comment: @techAddict82 its better to get courses per academy in single call rather than making multiple call, get json from server giving you {academy: {course1 : {name : name, id: id }, course2 : ... }}

Comment: @RaunakKathuria  `better` is a relative term. Have to parse data to html at one end or the other. What matters is they get parsed properly and into valid html. Amount of html being transferred isn't huge, although could definitely limit the requests

Comment: @techAddict82 you are hitting a server for every option so say three courses three server hit, it will be efficient to make one call to get all the courses per academy and play with it on frontend. Less latency much faster

Comment: @charlietfl not sure if I am following you about the spaces. But yes the select menu has three values being selected. I just want to select one per dropdown menu.

Comment: @RaunakKathuria How would I be able to make the ajax call and incorporate the results within the for loop of the script?

Comment: suggest you revisit your query logic, you make the same request for all 3 select tags with no GET params to differntiate them, then set 3 selected in each set returned

Comment: @charlietfl. Alright, please would you be able to write this in answer format in relation to my example. This would give me a base or foundation to the right path.

Comment: @charlietfl could you please suggest how to do this with GET params?

Comment: You need to load the courses by academy, right?

Comment: @Noupla.M. Yes that is correct. In the php code I manually specify this through variable `$id`.

Comment: SO if a academy provides 5 courses u need 5 drop downs also right?

Comment: @Nouphal.M Yes that is correct. In the jquery, I have hard coded `var option` for this specific example. But I am using php to fetch the number of rows that have courses offered by that academy and then assigning that value to `var option`

Comment: @techAddict82 Just to confirm the scenario, user select academy say id = 15, then it show 'how many courses offered' say 3 as in demo, then you want these three courses for the acadmey to be selected in the three select menus?

Comment: @RaunakKathuria Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to understand the issue here, do you need... - 1 dropdown to select an academy and then generate dynamically dropdowns to hold courses available for that academy in particular? (e.g. the academy here has 3 courses only so you'll end up with 3 dropdowns, each of them having only those 3 courses on their list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript insert into document.ready event

```
var option = 3,
    $course_catalog = $('#course_catalog');
showFields(option);

function showFields(option){ 
    $course_catalog.html('');
    // request only once
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getCourses.php",
        async : false,
        data: { 
            value : option
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
               // prepare select
                $course_catalog.append('<div id="course_' + i + '"><label>Course # '+i+'</label><br />'
                        +'<label>Course Name:</label>'
                        +'<select id="coursename_'+i+'" name="coursename_'+i+'" class="course_list">'
                        +'<option value="" >--- Select ---</option>"'
                        +'</select><br/><p id="date_'+i+'"></p></div></br>');

                var $el = $course_catalog.find('#coursename_' + i), 
                    val = 0,
                    index = 1;
                for(var n in data) {
                    var o = data[n];
                    if (o.academy_id > 0) {
                        if (index == i) {
                            val = o.id + ':' + o.name;
                            $course_catalog.find('#date_'+i).html('Start at: ' + o.start_date + ' until '+o.end_date);
                        }
                        index ++;
                    }
                    $el.append('<option value="' + o.id + ':' + o.name + '">'+o.name+'</option>');
                }
                $el.val(val);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PHP code:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
$id = 15;
//get the course list
$course_query = $db_con->prepare("
    SELECT 
        t.course_id, t.course_name, IFNULL(lj.academy_id, 0) as academy_id, lj.course_start_date, lj.course_end_date
    FROM courses_selection_list as t
    LEFT JOIN courses_by_academy as lj 
        ON (lj.course_id = t.course_id AND lj.academy_id = :id)
    ORDER BY t.course_id
");
$course_query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$data = $course_query->fetchAll();

$course_data = array();
foreach ($data as $row) { 
    $course_data[] = array(
       "id" => $row["course_id"],
       "name" => $row["course_name"],
       "academy_id" => $row["academy_id"],
       "start_date" => $row["course_start_date"],
       "end_date" => $row["course_end_date"],
    );
}  // foreach ($data as $row) {
echo json_encode($course_data);
```

Comment: Alright, I made the changes according to your answer but the dropdown menus are not getting displayed in [course_offerings.php](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/course_offering.php)

Comment: @techAddict82, remove `;` at the end `+'<option value="" >--- Select ---</option>"'`

Comment: Yes, I made that change. The console shows that `$course_catalog is not defined`

Comment: @techAddict82, I updated my answer. `$course_catalog` moved before call function, my mistake

Comment: It shows courses 1 and 2 with correct value `selected` but course #3(`Science`) is not showing at all as `selected`. Also the order of courses seems to be different.

Comment: @techAddict82, added `ORDER BY` to query, and fix begin value `$i = 1`

Comment: @techAddict82, also changed `$course_catalog.find('#coursename_' + i).append(data);` for store `---Select---` value

Comment: alright, thank you. One other advice, each course has a `start_date` and `end_date` how can I display those results in an input field beside each dropdown menu?

Comment: @techAddict82, now you can see my advice

Comment: Great advice! but the json is not returning anything at all.

Comment: Only the courses that are selected in the menu have a `course_start_date` and `course_end_date`. Check the updated `courses_by_academy` table above.

Comment: @techAddict82, sorry again have mistakes: second `$data` renamed to `$course_data`, fix `"start_date" => $row["course_start_date"],` and `"end_date" => $row["course_end_date"],`

Comment: @techAddict82, also fix name of columns in query: `lj.course_start_date, lj.course_end_date`

Comment: Great, that part is working. But Sergey, the `courses` are no longer being `selected`.

Comment: @techAddict82, change `val = o.id + ':' + o.name;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44213/discussion-between-techaddict82-and-sergey)

Comment: Please check the chat, I have another concern

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work is that your SQL queries are in the wrong order. You first want to get the `courses_by_academy` and then get the respective course from the `courses_selection_list`.

Also your approach to using Javascript in this context is a bit unreasonable, so I have removed it for displaying the dropdowns.

```
<?php
$id = 15;

//get the course list
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
    SELECT academy_id, course_name, course_id, 
           course_start_date, course_end_date
    FROM courses_by_academy
    WHERE academy_id = :id
");
if (!$db_select) return false;
if (!$db_select->execute(array(':id' => $id))) return false;
$results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (empty($results)) return false;
foreach ($results as $value) {

$course_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses_selection_list;");
$course_query->execute();

$data = $course_query->fetchAll();
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $row){
    $i += 1;

    echo '<div class="courses">';
    echo '<label>Course # <span>', $i, '</span></label><br />';
    echo '<label>Course Name:</label>';
    echo '<select name="coursename[]" class="course_list">';
    echo '<option>--- Select ---</option>"';

    echo "<option value='".$row["course_id"].":".$row["course_name"]."'";
    if ($value['course_id'] == $row['course_id']) {
        echo " selected='selected'";
    }
    echo ">". $row['course_name'] ."</option>";
}   
echo '</select></div></br>';
```

Note how I used `coursename[]` as the name for the SELECT: using this the PHP will receive this as an array in the POST request, as `$_POST["coursename"]`, so that you can use `foreach` to go through them.

I assume the Javascript is meant to be able to change the number of courses? I would take a different approach here:

```
$("#courses_offered").on("change", function() {
    var number_of_courses_offered = $('#courses_offered').val();
    var course_divs = $("div.courses");

    if (number_of_courses_offered < 1) {
        course_divs.hide();
        return;
    }

    course_divs.show();

    // to few courses displayed: add another one until the number fits
    while (course_divs.length < number_of_courses_offered) {

        // create an empty course div by using the first one and removing the 
        // selected attribute so that the first item "--- Select" is displayed
        var single_course_div = course_divs.first().clone(true);
        single_course_div.find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        // fix the course number
        single_course_div.find("span").text(course_divs.length + 1);

        // insert it after the last of the divs
        course_divs.last().after(single_course_div);

        course_divs = $("div.courses"); // update for the next while loop
    }

    // too many courses displayed: remove the last ones
    while (course_divs.length > number_of_courses_offered) {
        // remove the last div
        course_divs.last().remove();

        course_divs = $("div.courses"); // update for the next while loop
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a select box that lists all the academies available:

```
<select name="academy" id="acadaemy">
  <option value="1">Academy1</option>
    .............................
    .............................
  <option value="15">Academy15</option>
</select>
```

Then you can bind an onchange event for this select to display the desired courses.

```
 $('#acadaemy').on('change', function() {
           var option = this.value;
                   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "getCourses.php",
                    data: {
                            'ac_id': option
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                                  $('#course_catalog').html(data);
                        }
                    });
});
```

And in ur getCourses.php

```
Step 1:  fetch the POST value (here $_POST['ac_id']) and validate it
Step 2:  Get all courses.
Step 3:  Get all courses with specified academy id
Step 4:  Iterate result from step 3 and create each select tag.
Step 5:  Iterate result from Step 2 and create option tags and set selected.
Step 6:  Echo back the result.



<?php
     $id = $_POST['ac_id'];
     //Do something here to validate the post data

    $course_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses_selection_list;");
    $course_query->execute();

$data = $course_query->fetchAll();//All courses here
    $db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
        SELECT academy_id, course_name, course_id, 
               course_start_date, course_end_date
        FROM courses_by_academy
        WHERE academy_id = :id
    ");
$resultStr = '';

if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':id' => $id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // academy specific courses here
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    foreach ($results as $value) { // iterate academy courses
    $resultStr .= '<div class="course">';
    $resultStr .= '<select name="coursename[]" class="course_list">';
          foreach ($data as $row){ // iterate all courses
                        $result .= "<option value='".$row["course_id"].":".$row["course_name"]."'";
            if ($result['course_id'] == $row['course_id']) {
                $resultStr .= " selected='selected'";
            } 
                        $resultStr .= ">". $row['course_name'] ."</option>";
                  }
    $resultStr .= '</select>';
    $resultStr .= '</div>';
    }
echo $resultStr;
exit();
?>
```